# Wordpress: wp_update_post doesn't update the post with new data from a CSV

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, plugins, custom-post-type

I'm writing some code that will read a csv with information about real estate listings, and either create a post for that listing or update the current post. The title of each listing is the address, so if it detects a post with that address already made, I want it to update the current post. The posts are of a custom type "listing" with custom fields such as "_listing_address" (also the post_title) and "_listing_price", etc. Here is the part of the code that initializes the array for a new post or with data to update the new post:

```
$new_post = array(
        'post_title'   => convert_chars($data['csv_post_title']),
        'post_content' => wpautop(convert_chars($data['csv_post_post'])),
        'post_status'  => $opt_draft,
        'post_type'    => $type,
        'post_date'    => $this->parse_date($data['csv_post_date']),
        'post_excerpt' => convert_chars($data['csv_post_excerpt']),
        'post_name'    => $data['csv_post_slug'],
        'post_author'  => $this->get_auth_id($data['csv_post_author']),
        'tax_input'    => $this->get_taxonomies($data),
        'post_parent'  => $data['csv_post_parent'],
);
```

And here is the code that either creates a new post or (should) update an existing post:

```
if (!get_page_by_title( $new_post['post_title'], 'OBJECT', 'listing')) {
    $id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
} else {
    $old_post = get_page_by_title( $new_post['post_title'], 'OBJECT', 'listing' );
    $new_post['ID'] = $old_post->ID;
    $id = wp_update_post($new_post);
}
```

I can successfully create new posts with the code that I have, and it also successfully checks if another post has the same title, since it doesn't create duplicate posts. However, it doesn't actually update the posts. So if on my csv file I change the price of one of the listings from $29,900 to $30,000, when I re-upload the csv, it won't create a new post since the address didn't change, but it won't change price of the current post. I'm guessing it's a problem with the post ID's, but anything I've tried hasn't worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Other relevant information**:
I'm using the CSV Importer plugin for Wordpress, which I modified with the above code to check for duplicate posts and update them. I'm also using the Genesis framework and the Agentpress theme, which creates the listing custom type.

Comment: Where is `$new_post` coming from in your top code block? Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: Afterwards, add in the second parameter to `wp_update_post` and set it to `true`... Then `var_dump($id)` to see if there's a WP_Error.

Comment: The top code block with the creation code actually came after the array - I edited the question so that the code was in chronological order, my bad. When I set the 2nd parameter, I used `is_wp_error` see if it was a WP_Error, and it came back false, and the `var_dump` returns the ID's of the posts it "updated." I also used `var_dump` to test and see if the ID from the old post matched the ID it was inserting into the array, and it did, so I'm unsure now as to whether this might be a problem with the array not getting updated or with the way `wp_update_post` works

Comment: What's the post type? Could there be transient data that needs to be cleared? For example, PODS sometimes has the issue where you won't see certain updates until you clear the transient caches.

Comment: I fixed it! The problem was linked to using a function to create custom fields and not update them later on, and I posted the answer below. Thanks for your time though Half Crazed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that the code I had above creating an array didn't deal with any custom fields - those were handled by another function called later on, which used the `create_post_meta()` function for Wordpress to create the custom fields. Obviously this was a problem for me since I was trying to update post meta fields that had already been created. All I had to do was switch this to `update_post_meta()`, which both updates already created post meta or creates a new one if it hasn't. Hopefully this helps anyone who is using CSV Importer or has made their own CSV upload plugin and is struggling to both create and update posts from a CSV file.